# Changing database elements displayed in form based on input selection in Laravel

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I'm creating a form where the user first are presented with two radio buttons:

```
<div class="parent">
  <input class="myRadio" type="radio" name="var" value="choice1" required>
  <input class="myRadio" type="radio" name="var" value="choice2" required>
</div>
```

Depending on what the user selects, I want to display an array of elements that matches the selected choice:

```
@foreach ($elements as $key=>$element)
@if($element['choice'] == 'choice1')
  <img src="{{$element['src']}}">
@endif
@endforeach
```

But as mentioned these sections are in the same form element and loaded simultaneously, making it awkward to make a database call. Is there a simple way for me to keep this mainly front-end? I understand I can update the section with `.load()`, but it is the middle-part I am afraid I might be overthinking.

Edit: Just as a clarfication, what I in theory want to achieve is to replace `@if($element['choice'] == 'choice1')` with `@if($element['choice'] == input.value)`, then reload the foreach looped section of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript`.
(In this answer i will call radiobuttons->selector and elements ->selections)

1.Pass all datas from controller to view.

2.Calssify selections will show with each other by select each selector and assign css class to them and put them in seperate form but common target.

3.assign `onclick` event to each selector and call different functions in javascript.

4.In each function use `show()` to display elements you want and `hide()` to hide those which you like.

**Example**:

```
 <input onclick="rad1Select()">
  <input onclick="rad2Select()">
<form name="form1" action="/postpage" method="post">
<input  class="s1" value="{{fromModel}}">
<input class="s1" value="{{fromValue}}">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form name="form2" action="/postpage" method="post">
<input  class="s2" value="{{fromModel}}">
<input class="s2" value="{{fromValue}}">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

(InScript)

```
<script>
function rad1Select()
{
$(".s1").show();
$(".s2").hide();
}

function rad2Select(){
$(".s1").hide();
$(".s2").show();
}
</script>
```

You can pass forms to different action for better validation in it.